# python command to print docstrings in file

Tags: python

What is the command-line to print the docstrings in a given Python file?

I thought there was something like:

```
$ python --showhelp foo.py

Name                 Help
--------------------------------------------------
bar                  This is the docstring for bar().
baz                  This is the docstring for baz().
```

Comment: I have never come over anything that can do this while I have been coding in python. I think you have to either make a parser yourself or open Idle and use the built in help() function.

Comment: Similar response to @Mogget, I have only seen `print ClassName.__doc__` or `print ClassName.Method.__doc__` - meaning that you could fairly easily make a parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it: [`pydoc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html)

For this example file:

```
# foo.py

def bar():
  """this is the docstring for bar()"""
  print 'hello'


def baz():
  """this is the docstring for baz()"""
  print 'world'
```

you can print the docstrings to stdout with this command:

```
$ pydoc ./foo.py
Help on module foo:

NAME
    foo

FILE
    /path/to/foo.py

FUNCTIONS
    bar()
        this is the docstring for bar()

    baz()
        this is the docstring for baz()
```

You can also generate an HTML help file:

```
$ pydoc -w ./foo.py
wrote foo.html
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Note that the `./` is important; otherwise there will be no output.